# Google Tag Manager's "Click Listener" not detecting all clicks?

Tags: google-analytics, onclicklistener, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, click-tracking

I am using tag manager's "click listener" on a website I work on to better understand how visitors interact with a form. This is working fine on the form and I can see the "clicks" in analytics, however the tag which should fire on each click is NOT working for a specific button.

You can see the form/button in question by visiting www.vanleasing.com and choosing a make and model. After you've clicked "Find my van" you'll be taken to a page showing the vehicle. Now click "Quote me" to view the form.

The button which is causing me problems is the "Step 2" button at the bottom of the form and it's important that I can determine when it is clicked.

If anyone could take a quick look and let me know why my tag isn't firing when the "Step 2" button is clicked it would be a great help.

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already is a javascript click event on that button. That would not be the problem, but the function that is called returns "false". That prevents the Google click listener from working (you'd need to change that to "event.preventDefault()").